# Complete the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, methods

#Code Project : Shooting game.

You are creating a shooting game!

The game has two types of enemies, aliens and monsters. You shoot the aliens using your laser, and monsters using your gun. Each hit decreases the lives of the enemies by 1. The given code declares a generic Enemy class, as well as the Alien and Monster classes, with their corresponding lives count. It also defines the hit() method for the Enemy class.

You need to do the following to complete the program:

**1.** Inherit the Alien and Monster classes from the Enemy class.

**2.** Complete the while loop that continuously takes the weapon of choice from user input and call the corresponding object's hit() method.

**Sample Input:**

```
laser
laser
gun
exit
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Alien has 4 lives
Alien has 3 lives 
Monster has 2 lives
```

I completed 1st part , but need help with part 2.

```
class Enemy:
  name = ""
  lives = 0
  def __init__(self, name, lives):
    self.name = name
    self.lives = lives

  def hit(self):
    self.lives -= 1
    if self.lives <= 0:
       print(self.name + ' killed')
    else:
        print(self.name + ' has '+ str(self.lives) + ' lives')

class Monster(Enemy):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('Monster', 3)

class Alien(Enemy):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('Alien', 5)


m = Monster()
a = Alien()

while True:
    x = input()
    if x == 'exit':
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the community guidelines while asking any question on stackoverflow. Please check out this link [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi9n7m_zfnwAhURcCsKHa4CBNkQFjAAegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F334822%2Fhow-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions&usg=AOvVaw37Gc6jmkl2ZyGLUpRZ1RUn)

**Check out this code :**

```
while True:
    x = input()
    if x == 'exit':
        break
    elif x == 'laser':
        a.hit()
    elif x == 'gun':
        m.hit()
```